# Highcharts: Get visibility of series after legendItemClick

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a chart with multiple series which I would like to modify the options of, if two of the series have been disabled by clicking on the legend.

The following won't work as `visible` has the value of the state before it was clicked. Is there another way to do what I am trying to accomplish below?

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        events: {
            legendItemClick: function(event) {
                if(this.yAxis.series[0].visible && this.yAxis.series[1].visible) {
                    // do some action
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get this behavior a little modyfing your function:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    events: {
      legendItemClick: function(event) {
          var series = this.yAxis.series,
              seriesLen = series.length,
              visible = this.visible ? 1 : -1; 
              // +1 when visible series, because it will be changed after that callback

          for(var i = 0; i < seriesLen; i++) {
            if(!series[i].visible) {
              visible++;
            }
          }
          if(visible >= 2){
            //do some action
          }
      }
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: That won't work I think because I have more than two series. And I only want to check for the first two.

Comment: That wasn't in your question.. add: `if(visible >= 2 && this.index < 2)`to add action only if one of two first series was changed.